# Could You Please suggest me How to ignore HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URLHeader in IIS Server for Django RestAPI

Tags: django, iis, django-rest-framework, postman

When we call API from Postman with `X_ORIGINAL_URL` in headers
then we want to ignore `HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL`

[image]

```
ADD Inbound rules
Rule name: "set server variables"
Requested URL: "Matches the Pattern"
Using: "Regular Expressions"
Pattern: "^([a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2})/(.*)"
Conditions:
Input: "{Languages:{R:1}}"
Type: "Matches the Patterns"
Pattern: "(.+)"
Action:
Type: "Rewrite"
Rewrite URL: "{R:2}"
```

Comment: When people talk about IIS configuration, they usually paste the related XML elements from the configuration files (applicationHost.config or web.config) or screen shots of the related pages in IIS Manager.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, X-Original-URL is added by the URL Rewrite module and you cannot easily remove it. Maybe you can try to set HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL to something else by setting iis url rewrite rules. Select "View Server Variables..." and if you don't see HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL listed, select "Add..." and add the server variable. You can then go back and use it in your rules and create rules to replace that value.